# Sed Regex OSX find Roman numerals and replace with empty string. Error "unterminated substitute pattern"

Tags: regex, bash, macos, shell, sed

This is probably a Sed and shell scripting syntax issue as well as Regex.
(Edit: maybe an I/O issue, as the regex worked when reading the file within the bash shell, but the actual `.txt` file was not altered as desired)

Trying to prepare a `.txt` file for some natural language processing work. Wanted to delete some Roman numerals in a plain text file containing Shakespeare's sonnets, each sonnet beginning with a Roman numeral such as `IX.` and `XVIII.` which represents the title of the individual sonnet, including the decimal character.

Example intput text:

> XXV.
>
> Let those who are in favour with their stars
>
> Of public honour and proud titles boast,

Desired output:

> Let those who are in favour with their stars
>
> Of public honour and proud titles boast,

Following the example in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands), I tried all the following commands in Terminal bash shell:

`$ sed -i 's/[IVXLC]{1,}[.]//g' sonnets.txt`

`$ sed -i 's/[IVXLC]{1,}[.]/^$/g' sonnets.txt`

`$ sed -i 's/[IVXLC]{1,}[.]/()/g' sonnets.txt`

`$ sed -i 's/[IVXLC]{1,}[.]/[]/g' sonnets.txt`

The idea was to replace any match with an empty string. Since that didn't work, I tried to replace match with a space character:

`$ sed -i 's/[IVXLC]{1,}[.]/^ $/g' sonnets.txt`

No luck. All commands above returned the same error:

`sed: 1: "sonnets.txt": unterminated substitute pattern`

I tested the regex in the "find" field on https://regexr.com/ and it seemed to be correct. The target file was right in the working directory. Any idea what went wrong? What characters should I be using in the "replace" field of the Sed command? Should I modify the regex and/or the Sed command?

Comment: Can you paste example text ? What is the input and how do you like the output to look like. ?

Comment: I think the `{` and `}` need to be escaped. `\{` and `\}`. The square brackets may also need to be escaped not sure.

Comment: `{}[]` don't seem to be a problem when testing on https://regexr.com/

Comment: It doesn't matter what `regexr.com` says: what matters is what your `sed1 on your Mac does.  You either need to use extended regular expressions, enabled with `-E`, or you need to use `\{1,\}`.  You don't need to escape the square brackets.

Comment: Don't you also need to supply a file extension for `-i` on OS X? The improper escaping wouldn't lead to that error message, but I can't test.

Comment: It seems like an I/O issue, as the regex worked when reading the file content within the bash shell, but the actual .txt file did not change

Comment: @BenjaminW. — yes, you do provide an argument to `-i`.  As it stands, the 'regex' is being used as the extension for the backup, except that no backup is being made.

Comment: Note that the version of `sed` on Mac is the BSD version, not the GNU version.  The behaviours are different in many ways.

Comment: Tried `sed -i '.original' 's/[IVXLC]{1,}[.]//g'` and got `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jonathan Leffler mentioned in the comments, my Mac is using BSD `sed` and that's why the command didn't work.

So I installed GNU `sed` through Homebrew:

`brew install gnu-sed`

Then used the command:

`gsed -i 's/[IVXLC]\{1,\}[.]//g' sonnets.txt`

Typing in `gsed` invokes the GNU `sed`, and it worked as desired. It altered the content of the `.txt` file in place.

In this configuration, as @Hakan Baba mentioned, the regex did need to escape the curly braces:

`\{` `\}`

Comment: You may actually do without the range/limiting quantifier here, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets need to be escaped.

```
$ sed  's/[IVXLC]\{1,\}[.]//g'  sonnets.txt


Let those who are in favour with their stars

Of public honour and proud titles boast,
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the range (or *limiting* ) quantifier `{m,n}` that is not supported in your BSD `sed` version. Note that you may rewrite the `{1,}` quantifier using `[IVXLC][IVXLC]*` (one Roman "digit" followed with 0+ Roman digits):

```
sed -i 's/[IVXLC][IVXLC]*[.]//g' sonnets.txt
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, if you need to make sure you only match the Roman numbers at the start of the line, append `^` at the start of the pattern (and that means you may also omit `g` modifier at the end of the regex). To match them as whole words, add `[[:<:]]` leading word boundary at the start of the pattern.

Comment: Interesting idea with `[IVXLC][IVXLC]*`! For this particular document I was working with, it contains over 100 Roman numerals denoting all the sonnets written by Shakespeare. The `^` and `$` characters, which mark the beginning and end of the entire text input, probably would not apply.

Comment: However, `[[:<:]]` initial word boundary might be of interest.